# Deserialization with thrift

Tags: serialization, deserialization, thrift

I'm working about KBA TREC collection. A generic TREC collection contains a lot of documents that can be news, forums, etc.

When I download a generic document, it has the format `filename.sc.xz.gpg`:

- `gpg`: the file was encrypted and so I decrypted it with the apposite key;
- `xz`: the file was compressed and so I decompressed it;
- `sc`: the file was serialized and I MUST deserialize it.

The problem is with the process of deserialization. In the documentation I read that the data was serialized with thrift.

My question is: how can I use thrift to deserialize my file `filename.sc`?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Python or Java. I prefer Python.

Comment: A quiyck search yielded this: https://github.com/flamholz/py-thrift-validation-example/blob/master/util/serialization.py